# Pyspark org.postgresql.Driver java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, postgresql, pyspark

I am trying to insert a data frame into a Postgres table. I have downloaded the driver jar file, but after tweaking it I am still getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hossein/spark/advanced/connect_to_db/connect.py", line 37, in <module>
    dataframe.select("mesh_term", "mesh_tree").write.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=table_name, mode="overwrite", properties=jdbc_properties)
  File "/home/hossein/dev/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1340, in jdbc
  File "/home/hossein/dev/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
  File "/home/hossein/dev/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
  File "/home/hossein/dev/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o51.jdbc.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
```

This is my code:

```
file_path = 'all_mesh_retrieved.json'

with open(file_path, 'r') as json_file:
    # Load the JSON data
    all_mesh_terms = json.load(json_file)

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "postgresql-42.6.0.jar").config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "postgresql-42.6.0.jar").getOrCreate()

dict_list = [{"mesh_term": key, "mesh_tree": value} for key, value in all_mesh_terms.items()]

# creating a dataframe
dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(dict_list)

jdbc_url = "jdbc:postgresql://xxx.cs.illinois.edu:5432/zzz"
jdbc_properties = {
    "user": "abcd",
    "password": "efg",
    "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"
}

table_name = "yyy.mesh"

dataframe.select("mesh_term", "mesh_tree").write.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=table_name, mode="overwrite", properties=jdbc_properties)
```

I have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68513383/pyspark-dataframe-error-due-to-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-postgresql) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/apachespark/comments/qhv03n/error_javalangclassnotfoundexception/) as well, but still getting the same error.

Thanks.